# How to set up ODBC provider for Mysql in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, odbc

I've just downloaded Mysql-obbc-connector driver, and how can I enable this driver to connect to Mysql from vbscript. How can I set up new odbc provider in Odbc source administrator window in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql.  The one for MySQL Connector/ODBC 3.51 is probably the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For VBsript you probably want to use the OLEDB driver and the [OLEDB connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p27).  See this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393725/mysql-oledb-driver).  OLEDB is the native database connectivity in VBScript.
Although if you do want to use the ODBC  connector, see the the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html).